# Getting error "Unable to create a new remote session" while running appium on AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, appium, aws-device-farm

I am trying to test a web application on mobile browser on Android. It is perfectly running locally but on AWS Device Farm it is throwing error ""Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: connect timed out".
Can anyone help.
**I am attaching the logs for reference**

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Setting up your device. This usually takes 2-3 minutes.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Start executing testspec ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Entering phase install ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ export APPIUM_VERSION=1.14.2
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ avm $APPIUM_VERSION
/usr/bin/avm: line 261: appium: command not found
[36m exists[0m : [90m[0m
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ if ; then
DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2;
else
DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID;
DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1;
fi`enter code here`
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Entering phase pre_test ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TESTNG_JAR
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/*
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/dependency-jars/*
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ if ; then echo "Start appium server for android"; (appium --log-timestamp --default-capabilities "{\"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"automationName\":\"UiAutomator2\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\", \"browserName\":\"Chrome\", \"chromedriverExecutable\":\"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE\"}" >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &); fi
Start appium server for android
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ if ; then echo "Start appium server for iOS"; (appium --log-timestamp --default-capabilities "{\"usePrebuiltWDA\": true, \"derivedDataPath\":\"$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH\", \"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"automationName\":\"XCUITest\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\", \"browserName\":\"Safari\"}" >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &); fi
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ start_appium_timeout=0; while https://forums.aws.amazon.com/; do
if https://forums.aws.amazon.com/;
then
echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
exit 1;
fi;
grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
if https://forums.aws.amazon.com/;
then
echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
break;
else
echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
sleep 1;
start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
fi;
done;
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Entering phase test ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ echo "Navigate to test package directory"
Navigate to test package directory
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ echo "Start Appium TestNG test"
Start Appium TestNG test
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH org.testng.TestNG -testjar *-tests.jar -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Running the tests in 'Test' with parallel mode:false
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Adding method selector: org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector@1ef7fe8e priority: 10
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Creating TestClass for http://ClassImpl class=com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Adding method AppiumTest1.run()https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ on TestClass class com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Including method com.TestScripts.run()
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Running:
/tmp/scratchOES4mC.scratch/test-packageafEvaA/testng.xml

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Created 1 TestRunners
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ excluded groups:[]
===== Test class
com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1
@Test AppiumTest1.run()pri:0, instance:com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1@3cda1055
======
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ RUNNING: Suite: "Test" containing "1" Tests (config: /tmp/scratchOES4mC.scratch/test-packageafEvaA/testng.xml)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ INVOKING: "Test" - com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.run()
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Invoking com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.run
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ FAILED: "Test" - com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.run() finished in 121729 ms
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: connect timed out
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.run(AppiumTest1.java:48)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ... 36 more
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ... 41 more
===== Invoked methods
AppiumTest1.run()pri:0, instance:com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1@3cda1055 1020923989
=====
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/Suite/Test.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/Suite/Test.xml
FAILED: run
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Original error: connect timed out
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
at com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.run(AppiumTest1.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
... 41 more
===============================================
Test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ===============================================
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Test
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ===============================================

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@77afea7d: 81 ms
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3d04a311: 5 ms
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/toc.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/Test.properties
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/index.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/main.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/groups.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods-alphabetical.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods-alphabetical.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods-alphabetical.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/classes.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/reporter-output.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/methods-not-run.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/Suite/testng.xml.html
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/old/index.html
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@299a06ac: 6 ms
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/testng-failed.xml
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/Suite/testng-failed.xml
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by https://forums.aws.amazon.com/: 3 ms
Creating /tmp/customer_log_directoryBh1aB8/test-output/junitreports/TEST-com.TestScripts.AppiumTest1.xml
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@5f8ed237: 5 ms
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2e5c649: 24 ms
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Entering phase post_test ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Finish executing testspec ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ ########### Setting upload permissions ###########
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ Tearing down your device. Your tests report will come shortly.
```

Comment: Looks like your logs are a bit messed up. Can you fix them? Also, it seems like you also posted on the AWS Device Farm [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=329788&tstart=0) about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by changing Appium server from 0.0.0.0:4723 to 127.0.0.1:4723